# Cannot find correct file called qtnetwork4.dll

Tags: qt

Guys I've written app in qt and when trying to run it (double click on *.exe) I'm getting error that this application cannot start because qtnetwork4.dll isn't available. I've searched my drive and I found few files with this name (and copied one by one every time trying to run my app) but none of them seems to work. How can I solve it?

Comment: maybe qtnetwork4d.dll instead qtnetwork4.dll required? It's for app builded in debug configuration

Comment: @triclosan no, it's for release

Comment: possible duplicate of [DLL is missing when launching Qt GUI app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114207/dll-is-missing-when-launching-qt-gui-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, DLL are looked for in folder where executable lies, then using "PATH" environenment variable.

In your case, you want to put your dll along your executable, taking them from the sdk you're using to compile

The following [page](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/BuildingQtInstallers) provides a lot of additional information on the subject (example, plugins, strategy for building installers)

To force using QtNetwork and linking it, you have to put

```
 QT += network
```

in your poject file.

If you're sure you're not using it, you can use

```
 QT -= network
```

Comment: hi, I've added this line but it seems to doesn't make any difference. Still getting same error ;) any ideas?

Comment: without more information, can't really help. You should share code or details if you want more in depth answer.

Answer (score 2):

place into your *.exe - folder appropriate dll-s from %QT_PATH%\bin\

Comment: how can I check what is my QT_PATH?

Comment: this is the path where qt is installed. For example C:\Qt\4.7.4\

Comment: Kr ok thanks, another question, I don't need network functionality, how can I compile my app so it doesn't need this file?

Comment: as i remember, appropriate dll-s added on-demand (at linking stage). That means some part of your code uses qnetwork features.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called Dependency Walker that will let you know what functions in qtnetwork4.dll are being used in your program. It can be found at the following:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

All of the DLLs your program use will be from the same installation as the qmake.exe that is used to compile the program. If you are using Qt Creator you can see where the qmake.exe your using is located by going to:

> tools->options->Qt4

Get the DLLs that are located at the path displayed here to make sure they will work with your program.