# Can't find libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll in QT 5.0.1

Tags: qt

I'm trying to run my "hello world" on Windows XP 32bit. I know that I must deploy some libs with my exe but can't find libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll in QT directory. I thought that all mingw libs are ships with QT instalator. Why it is missing? Must I download mingw and copy it?

Comment: If it is not there you probably have to download it and add it (At least in one of my open source projects, the maintainer of the Windows installer added that file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [DLL is missing when launching Qt GUI app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114207/dll-is-missing-when-launching-qt-gui-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MinGWs compiler to compile your "hello world", than you already have all needed files in your system. `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is MinGWs library, you can find it in path where your MinGW is installed `...\MinGW\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`.

And try to make search on all of your system for that file.

Comment: Ok I downloaded MinGW, but now I get error "__gxx_personality_v0" in libstdc++6.dll

Comment: Ok I installed QT on my new clear Windows XP virtual mashine and now everything works fine. Seems that on old mashine I had mess with MinGW

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you install MinGW too? or just a blank QT installation?